# A value at a point of continuity is determined by dense subset?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I know that given topological space $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, such that $D\subseteq X$ is a dense subset and both spaces are Hausdorff, a continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is determined by its values on $D$. Is the remark also remains true when dealing with not necessarily continuous functions on the whole space, but rather at point. More concretely, if $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0\in X$, is the value of $f(x_0)$ determined by $f\vert_D$?
I know that determing continuity of a function at a point, is saying that $x_0$ is in the interior of $f^{-1}[V]$ for all $f(x_0)\in V\in \tau_Y$, but lately I have been confusing myself alot.

Comment: There is a filter $\mathscr{F}$ on $D$ that converges to $x_0$. By continuity at $x_0$ we have $f(\mathscr{F}) \to f(x_0)$.

Comment: n your 1st sentence, no restrictions on $X$ are needed. Only $Y$ is required to be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is Hausdorff and if $D$ is a dense subset of  $X$:

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ be continuous at $x_0$ with $f|_D=g|_D.$

By contradiction, suppose $f(x_0)\ne g(x_0).$ Let $V_f, V_g$ be disjoint open subsets of $Y$ with $f(x_0)\in V_f$ and $g(x_0)\in V_g.$

By definition of continuity at a point, there are open subsets $U_f, U_g$ of $X$, each containing $x_0$, such that $f[U_f]\subseteq V_f$ and $g[U_g]\subseteq V_g .$

Now $U_f\cap U_g$ is open in $X,$ and non-empty (because it contains $x_0$) so there exists $d\in D\cap U_f\cap U_g.$

So $f(d)\in V_f$ but also $f(d)=g(d)\in V_g,$ which is absurd because $V_f,V_g$ are disjoint.

Comment: Kudos for using the $f[U]$ notation for image of sets!